# NSString Memory Bug/Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have UITextField of username and password, once the user hit the submit button  I do

```
 NSString* user_name;
 NSString* pass_word;
 UITextField * username;
 UITextField * password;
 NSString * url;

 user_name=username.text;
 pass_word=password.text;


  url = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"devices.json?user=%@&pswd=%@", user_name,pass_word];
```

However, when I try that, sometimes I got EXEC_BAD_ACCESS issue with url, I used the Zombie tool and nailed it %@ is the one causing issue with url string.  %@ expecting a NSString of user_name, pass_word but somehow in the process, the user_name and pass_word got mutated and got some junk values, not NSString anymore.

I try to use [user_name retain]; [pass_word retain]; [url retain]; but didn't help.  It keep having EXEC_BAD_ACCESS issue with %@ parameter of the url.

secondly I able to output the user_name, pass_word, it sometimes got some values that doesn't make sense. I don't where they got those values. I didn't put those values in. I am making a http call. somehow the http returned values sneaked inside the pass_word, and user_name, I have no idea why it's doing that.

Comment: Is this all your code exactly the way it's really used?

Comment: Can you post the entire method that is invoked when the submit button is pressed? Cherry picked code isn't that helpful.

Comment: Try creating property to the textfield and then synthesize it and see the result. I think that should work.

Comment: Is this your real code? That code won't even compile — it has a syntax error in the `stringWithFormat:` line.

Comment: @Chuck Yeah, he's got an extra bracket at url = [[

Comment: @lilzz In your code above you're sending the password in cleartext - probably not a good idea even if you're going to end up using HTTPS. Try doing NSString *user_name = username.text; all in one line instead of pre-allocating the object.

Comment: ignore the [[, I have to cut and paste portion of the code. I have some many files spread out immpossible to upload.  I try to synthesize the UITextfield, didn't help.    I declare NSString *user_name, *pass_word in common.h file which many files need to access that one.

Comment: NSString *user_name, *pass_word values got invaded from some source unexpected.

Comment: @lilzz you have to post your actual code or nobody is going to be able to help you. Since you're responding but not actually editing, I'm going to vote to close this question since it can't be answered in its current state.

Comment: I think Jack Lawrence might have nailed it.

Comment: woohoo! If it ends up working, mark it as correct :)

Comment: Jack, I suspect that's the case. I need to verify. Those NSString defined in the common.h got corrupted for whatever reason. A singleton might be the way. I'll get back to this.

Comment: Jack, you da man, I verified using a singleton it works now instead of putting those string in common.h    btw, it's ridiculous some folks don't understand intricacies of the question and start to knock on quality of the question. But who care. I only need the expert level opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment:

> I declare NSString *user_name, *pass_word in common.h file which many
>   files need to access that one.

Unless you've got a singleton class, every time you alloc/init a new `Common` object it's going to have trash values. Objective-C best practices recommend against this sort of design. For most data, it's fine to store in a plist or in `NSUserDefaults`, but for the username and password string, you should store it in the keychain. Even better, you should store your password as a hash if the server will accept it.

Then use a category on NSString (call it something like NSString+Authentication) that has methods to pull the data from the keychain as well as insert it into the keychain.

Answer (score 2):

> secondly I able to output the user_name, pass_word, it sometimes got some values that doesn't make sense.

this usually means that you assign not initialized variables... and it explains the crashes if you try to nslog the values. but it's not possible to find out what's wrong from the part of the code you have included in your answer.

try to log the contents of username and password. (the uitextfields) .. you should use better variable names.

Comment: NSLog contains %@ expecting NSString, if it mutated and becoming something else other then NSString then NSLog would also crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the allocation as well and see if it helps:

```
url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"devices.json?user=%@&pswd=%@", user_name,pass_word];
```

Comment: How would this help at all? `+stringWithFormat:` is just a convenience method that calls through to `-initWithFormat:`.

Comment: the difference is that the stringWithFormat returns an autorelease string and this one would create a memory leak .. I don't think it will help.

Comment: Yeah, this change won't fix the OP's problem.

Comment: Okay. I'm still learning a lot :) Just recently started enjoying iOS.